# Browser responsive design mode and desktop scaling

Tags: html, browser, bootstrap-4, windows-10

I'm trying to see how my web application (using Bootstrap 4) will look like on different devices. So, I use Firefox Responsive Design mode to check it out.

The problem I'm having is how to also account for Windows 10 Display Scaling (found under "Scale and layout" in Desktop settings)?

*On bigger monitors nowadays users mostly use at least 125% or 150%.